# Issues with int arrays

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to replicate a DFA/NFA machine with printing transitions.
And am reaching errors when attempting to access values from my preset array and assign them to the newState variable.

So far I've tried moving variables within scope bodies, re-assigning variables and separating the try catch function to ensure the values of binaryValue and state are actually being correctly set.

The exception that occurs is array out of bounds. However i don't see what values requested are out of bounds.
Any help and advice would be appreciated

```
public class BinaryStringChecker {

    private static boolean checker;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //user inputed variable
        String userValue;

        //checker for binary values variable
        checker = false;

        //NFA/DFA start State
        int state = 0;

        //transition array
        int stateArray [][] = {{1,0},{2,0},{5,3},{4,4},{5,3},{6,4},{6,6}};

        //User input 
        Scanner usersInput = new Scanner (System.in);


        //Introduction
        System.out.println("Implimented DFA, will accept binary strings over alphabet Σ= {0, 1} that contain two pairs of adjacent 0’s separated by an even number of alphabet symbols.");

        //do while to check if values only consist of 0s and 1s
        do{
            System.out.println("Please enter desired string: ");

            userValue = usersInput.next();
            if (userValue.matches("[01]+")) {
                System.out.println("Checking "+userValue);
                checker = true;
                usersInput.close();
                }
            else {
                System.out.println("Thats not a binary number");
                }
            }
        while (checker == false);

        //assigning users input value
        String str = userValue; 

        //taking binary list from STL class
        STL.StringtoList(str);      

        //assigning list
        List<Character> 
        chars = STL.StringtoList(str); 

        //getting binary string length
        int stringLength;
        stringLength = chars.size(); 

        // Print the list of characters 
        System.out.println(chars); 

        //sequential iteration through users binary string 
        for (int i=0; i<stringLength; i++) {

            //taking value from position in list
            Character binaryValue = chars.get(i);

            try {
                int newState = stateArray[state][binaryValue];              
                state = newState;
                System.out.println("Current state:"+state);
                }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Somethings wrong here 1");
            }


        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: What's the code for `STL`? Please post code as a [reprex].

Comment: Also what errors are you getting?

Comment: Side note: that single `STL.StringtoList(str);` seems superfluous. Also instead of `System.out.println("Somethings wrong here 1");` you should print the actual exception, e.g. via `e.printStacktrace()`.

Comment: I suspect you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at this line: `int newState = stateArray[state][binaryValue];` Why? Because `binaryValue` probably isn't just 0 or 1 (actually it's a `Character` so even if the value was `'0'` that wouldn't be equal to the integer 0). Depending on whether this is appropriate for your algorithm or not you could do something like `[binaryValue.charValue() % 2]`.

Comment: you could use `int binaryValue = chars.get(i) - '0';` to work with integer `0` and `1`

Comment: Thank you for all the comments, Lino's suggestion worked. And Thomas description helped my understanding!